# A question about using just and only

Tags: word-usage

This is my first question here.
I don't know the difference between"only" and "just".
Can anyone help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! Click on that question that Eilia has shown. If it does not answer your question then you can come back and ask here again. However please can you say exactly what your problem is? Do you have examples where you think the words are the same or different?

Comment: My ***only*** reaction is to think it's ***just*** possible OP thinks the two words are always interchangeable. Only they're not.